What is the difference between and לִשְׁמֹר and לַעֲשׂוֹת?
The Mishna Avos (4:5) says
רַבִּי יִשְׁמָעֵאל בְּנוֹ אוֹמֵר, הַלּוֹמֵד תּוֹרָה עַל מְנָת לְלַמֵּד, מַסְפִּיקִין בְּיָדוֹ לִלְמֹד וּלְלַמֵּד. וְהַלּוֹמֵד עַל מְנָת לַעֲשׂוֹת, מַסְפִּיקִין בְּיָדוֹ לִלְמֹד וּלְלַמֵּד לִשְׁמֹר וְלַעֲשׂוֹת - He who learns in order to teach, it is granted to him to study and to teach; But he who learns in order to practice, it is granted to him to learn and to teach and to guard and practice.
What is the difference between "לִשְׁמֹר and לַעֲשׂוֹת"?

it seems that lishmor is referring to the negative mitzvot, and la'asot to the positive

The Tosfot Yom Tov explains it well:

לשמור ולעשות. שאע"פ שלא היתה כונתו אלא לעשות מספיקין בידו גם לשמור מהעבירות. שלא יהא כטובל ושרץ בידו. כך כתב במד"ש ובמשנת אבות שמא"י נמחק לשמור. וכן נראה דודאי שבכלל על מנת לעשות יש ג"כ לשמור מן העבירות. כי חלילה שיהא כוונת העושה ואינו נשמר מן העבירות טוב בעיני ה' ויפיק רצונו וכמו שכתבתי בתחלת המשנה אבל כוונת לעשות כלומר לקיים התורה:

Sefaria Translation:

TO KEEP(לשמור) AND TO DO(לעשות). Even though his intent was only “to
do”(לעשות), he is given the ability “to keep”(לשמור) away from sin, in
order that he not be “one who immerses while holding a rodent”—so
Midrash Shmuel. In a copy of Avot from the land of Israel the word “to
keep”(לשמור) does not appear, and this seems to be the correct text.
For “to do”(לעשות) would obviously include keeping away from sin; as I
wrote earlier, far be it that that doing positive commandments but not
keeping away from negative ones be good in G-d’s eyes and an
expression of His will! “To do”(לעשות), rather, means simply to keep
all the laws of the Torah.

Note: I added the hebrew words within () for better understanding

A couple more reasons in addition to the other answer
The Yachin says that the two expressions are emphasising "zachor" the remembering of the Torah injunctions and "shamor" the keeping of the Torah. In his words:

זכור ושמור ב' עניינים הם. דזכור היינו שיתעסק במחשבתו בעניין ההוא. ואעפ"כ אפשר שישכחהו לאחר זמן. אבל שמור היינו לאו דוקא שיתעסק עתה מחשבתו בהעניין, רק שהעניין שמור בלבו כמאו דמונח בקופסא, וא"א שישתכח מלבו, כדבר השמור במקום צנוע, דבכל עת שירצה ימצאנו
Remember and Keep are two (distinct) matters. Since "remembering" means that one busies themselves thinking about the matter, and yet, it is possible that he may forget after some time has elapsed. But "keeping" means not specifically thinking about the matter, rather that the matter is preserved in his heart as if it were placed in a box and as a consequence is impossible that he forget it from his heart. It is like something that is kept in a concealed place that whenever he wants he will be able to find it.

The Yein Levanon says similar to what has already been suggested. Lishmor is relating to negative mitzvos and Laasos - positive mitzvos. As such, just as a person makes his soul and habituates himself to observe the mitzvos he has done, so too, he must make his soul habituate himself to "guard" ("lishmor") against the transgression. "Laasos" ("to do") therefore represents the natural follow-on. In other words, a person acts following the wisdom they have acquired. The wisdom ingrained in one's heart, habituates the soul to turn away from evil and do good, whilst also leading him to do many other mitzvos.
